# Recursively change black to white in image with numpy

Tags: numpy, image-processing

What's the best way to remove large shadowed regions from greyscaled images. I'm struggling to write a method that takes a 2d Numpy array A and an entry (x,y) in A, and "crawls" through the array changing any (x',y') entry "connected" to (x,y) from 0 to 255. What I mean by connected is there's some path of 0 valued entries from (x,y) to (x',y'). Here's a picture of what I mean.

[image]

The black region at the bottom should all be set to grayscale 255. I'm almost positive this algorithm should be recursive, is there a fast way to do this in numpy, or using PIL?

EDIT:

OK thanks for the advice, here's what I've been able to come up with;

```
def creep(data, x, y):
    data[x, y]=255 
    for (i,j) in [(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)]:
        x, y = x + i, y + j 
        try:
            if data[x, y]==0:
                return creep(data, x, y)
        except:
            pass 
    return data 

def crop_big_region(data):
    """ Looks for black regions in image and makes them white """
    n, m = data.shape
    r = int(0.012*min(n,m)) 
    num_samples = int(0.0001*n*m)
    for _ in xrange(0,num_samples):
        x, y = numpy.random.randint(r,n - r), numpy.random.randint(r,m -r)
        if numpy.all(data[x-r:x+r, y-r:y+r] == 0):
            data[x,y] = 255
            data = creep(data, x, y)
    return data
```

It seems to sort of work, except it just returns lines, instead of filling out the entire region.

[image]

Think I'm just too tired to figure out the recursive step here properly.

Comment: You'll have to refine your algorithm a bit, otherwise anywhere there are 2 or more adjacent black pixels they will all be turned white, eliminating the shadow as well as the printing.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://www.diybookscanner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=2997. The program in question, [Scan Tailor](http://scantailor.org/), is open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Boaz pointed out is more an image processing question than a python question. You can achieve the desired result using the so-called *adaptive thresholding*. [Scikits-image](http://scikit-image.org/) has a nice implementation available, with a complete tutorial here:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_threshold_adaptive.html

You will need to tune it a bit, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well - it is not really "python related question" more of an image processing question.

I think you can have 2 options:
1. Use edge detection, and then iterate to see that the area is big enough
look at [Image outline using python/PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319767/image-outline-using-python-pil) for example.
2. Use OpenCV. Don't know it well - but this code seems to do something rather close to what you are trying to achieve 
[Python: detect black squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883023/python-detect-black-squares)